Simplification of formula
I am trying to solve some plasma system with the governing equations (after normalization)
$$ \frac{\partial n_s}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(n_s u_s) = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\partial u_p}{\partial t} + u_p \frac{\partial u_p}{\partial x} = - \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} $$
$$ \frac{\partial u_n}{\delta t} + u_n \frac{\partial u_n}{\partial x} = \sigma \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} $$
$$ n_e^(\gamma - 2) \frac{\partial n_e}{\partial x} = \beta \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} $$
$$  \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x^2} = - \rho $$
where $$ \rho = n_p - (1-\mu)n_e - \mu n_n $$
To derive K-dV equation for such system we apply the stretched coordinates:
$$ \xi = \epsilon^{1/2} (x- V_p t), \tau = \epsilon^{3/2} t $$
and we expand the variables in power series of $\epsilon$
$$ n_s = 1  + \epsilon n_s^{(1)} + \epsilon^2 n_s^{(2)}+ .... $$
$$ u_s = 0  + \epsilon u_s^{(1)} + \epsilon^2 u_s^{(2)}+ .... $$
$$ \phi = 0  + \epsilon \phi^{(1)} + \epsilon^2 \phi^{(2)}+ .... $$
$$ rho = 0  + \epsilon \rho^{(1)} + \epsilon^2 \rho^{(2)}+ .... $$
where the s, represents species (e for electrons, p for positive ions, n for negative ions)
Now by expressing the governing equations in terms of $\xi, \tau$ and the power series, then equating the coefficients of lowest power of $\epsilon$, (which is 3/2), we should have:
$$ u_p^{(1)} = \frac{\psi}{V_p}, n_p^{(1)} = \frac{\psi}{V_p^2} $$
$$ u_n^{(1)} = \frac{- \sigma \psi}{V_p}, n_n^{(1)} = \frac{- \sigma \psi}{V_p^2} $$
$$ n_e^{(1)} = \beta \psi, \rho^{(1)} = 0 $$
where $\psi = \phi^{(1)}$ so, $V^2_p$ must be:
$$ V^2_p =  \frac{(1+ \sigma - \mu \sigma)} {(\mu \beta)} $$
but I got:
$$ V^2_p = \frac{(1+ \mu \sigma)}{((1- \mu)\beta)} $$
I wonder what is the problem.

Context? What are $\mu, \sigma, \beta$?

As it stands, these are not equivalent (if $\mu=0$, say, the top one is just $\frac 1{\beta}$ while the bottom is undefined).  In fact, it's hard to find choices for the parameters that makes the definitions coincide.

These are some normalization constants, the thing is when I do the mathematical steps I get the first formula but the formula 2 is written in the paper I use

Edit your question and add more details on the mathematical steps.

Okay, wait a minute.

Is it possible that your definition of $\mu$ is different from the one used in the paper? If this is the case, then formula 1 is equivalent to formula 2 if $\mu_1=1-\mu_2$, where $\mu_1$ is your $\mu$ and $\mu_2$ is the paper's $\mu$.

I don't know, I just followed the steps. Me and my friend got nearly the same answer but I don't know why.

They are not equal.
Among many ways to show this,
the first goes to $\infty$
as $\mu \to 1$
while the second does not.
